# SOC vs ARM Core

Tags: arm, soc, peripheral

I am trying to understand the difference between SoC ( System on Chip ) and ARM Core.

In the following post, I have read "The typical ARM processor in use today is integrated with peripherals on a single IC called a SoC, system on a chip."

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599579/arm-linux-reboot-process

Consider the following i.MX6Q Block Diagram.

[image]

What are the peripherals here: GPU,VPU, IPU ..

Comment: What is the difference between a motor and a car?

Comment: GPU and VPU are defined in the diagram you posted, and IPU's meaning can be inferred very easily from the diagram.

Comment: So, in the above diagram ARM Core only means the block containing : " ARM Cortex A9 MPCore Platform "

Comment: ARM is an achitecture maintained by ARM organization , manufacturers base on its specification to make MCU, SoC,... You can read about SoC here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip and ARM  here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture